# YA book with animal bioengineering and maybe aliens

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult

I remember reading this young adult book series in 2012-14 maybe.

From what I can remember there was animal and human DNA testing, at some point in the book they discover the failed experiments/babies preserved in jars. I think there was an element of like good and bad animals/aliens they were taking samples from so maybe there was a ‘bad’/‘evil’ child produce as a result that became the villain?

I also remember crop circles that indicated the appearance of aliens. One of the books ended with a female protagonists pregnant from kissing an alien?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You say this is a series; do you mean that the two scenes you mention are in the same book or different books?  Do you remember any details of the cover art?